# Integral of divergence equal to divergence of integral?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Just as the heading reads...is the integral of the divergence of a vector field equal to the divergence of the integral of a vector field?

$\int\nabla\cdot\vec U dz = 0$

same as

$\frac\partial\partial_x \int u(x,y,z)  dz +\frac\partial\partial_y \int v(x,y,z)  dz +\frac\partial\partial_z \int w(x,y,z)  dz =0$

Is this statement true? The integral is arbitrary and can be taken over any coordinate. Basically I have to integrate the divergence of a vector field and I'm not sure if I can simply move the divergence operator outside the integral?

OR should it read:

$\int \frac\partial\partial_x u(x,y,z)  dz + \int \frac\partial\partial_y  v(x,y,z)  dz + \int \frac\partial\partial_z w(x,y,z)  dz =0$

EDIT: Tried to make it more clear by example. The limits of integration cover the full scope of the z-coordinate which is bounded from say A to B.

Comment: This interchange doesn't come for free; you need some regularity for it to work.

Comment: Regularity? Can you elaborate or point me to a reference?

Comment: Please specific the scope of the integral and of $\nabla$. Otherwise, it looks just like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360087/limits-of-integration-and-derivative

Comment: It's the same problem as interchanging integration and differentiation, just managed in each variable separately.

Comment: @ user251257: Thanks for pointing that out...I guess it would be the same question if I considered 1D only.

Comment: @Ian: So in general, NO, it's not true? There would have to be special conditions in order for it to be true?

Comment: If $\int$ operates over the domain of $\vec U$, then $\int \vec U$ is a constant. You need some room for variation in $\int \vec U$.

Comment: Okay, now it makes more sense. You might find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @ user251257: I think I follow what you're saying. In my updated example, if I take $ \frac \partial_z \int w(x,y,z)dz $over the full z-coordinate, then the integral is a constant and the $ \frac \partial_z $ of that is simply zero? In other words don't do it?

Comment: Sorry...couldn't figure out how to add math in comments

Comment: @ user251257 ahhhh...good old Leibniz rule...forgot about that

Comment: @user251257 You're talking about the first equation here, correct?[http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html]

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that your integral boundaries are constant and not functions.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks! That answers my question. Do you know how I close this or mark it answered?

Comment: I post a quick answer. I don't think you could close it otherwise. or you have delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For terms like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int u(x,y,z) \mathrm dz$ you could apply the Leibniz integral rule, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.